# UIAlertController is not working in model class

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to show an alert. But I want to show it by creating a function in another class and call that function from a viewcontroller. But it does not work.

Here is code from my LoginViewController:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        LoginModel().show_alert()
    }
}
```

Here is code from my LoginModel:

```
class LoginModel{

    let controller = LoginViewController()

    public func show_alert(){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Some Message", 
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: 
       nil))

        controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the reference of `UIViewController` subclass to your LoginModel class, to present the `UIAlertViewController` on `LoginViewController`. You should call show alert once the LoginViewController view is appeared on the screen, move the call to ViewWillApear or viewDidApear method

```
    final class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidApear(animated)
            LoginModel().show_alert(on: self)
        }
    }

    final class LoginModel {

        public func show_alert(on vc: UIViewController) {
             let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Some Message",
                                      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
             alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:
            nil))
            vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   }
```

ideally **you should not create the UI related methods in model classes, they should be on on UIViewController/UIView classes or their extension methods. Model classes should not know anything about UI stuff**. So you can easily create simple extension method on UIViewController and call the showAlert method from viewController.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(_ title: String = "Alert", message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:
            nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

you can call this method from UIViewController like

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    showAlert(message: "This is alert message")
}
```

Comment: tried this but does not show. 

Error: Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fb4af093e00> on <ProArt.LoginViewController: 0x7fb4aef2b8e0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: read the complete answer, you cannot call the showAlert method from viewDidLoad as the view is not shown yet.

Comment: please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Reminder:** Your model shouldn't know about any UI related stuffs. Instead you should create an extension to UIViewController, or create free function

As a free function

```
 func showAlertViewOnto(controller: UIViewController, detailInfo: (title: String?, message: String?), handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil ) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title:detailInfo.title , message: detailInfo.message,  preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:
            handler))
        controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

As an extension to your UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController {

     func showAlertView(detailInfo: (title: String?, message: String?), handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil ) {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title:detailInfo.title , message: detailInfo.message,  preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:
                handler))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

To Use it

```
  showAlertViewOnto(controller: self, detailInfo: (title: "Hello ", message: "welcome to our service"), handler: { _ in
        // here you can add code once ok is pressed

    })
```

Comment: tried this but does not work. Gives a waning. 

Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fb4af093e00> on <ProArt.LoginViewController: 0x7fb4aef2b8e0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your code. An instance of LoginViewController is already present (in the navigation stack or is the initial view controller) which appears on the screen.

You created a new instance of LoginViewController in your model class

> `let controller = LoginViewController()`

which is not added to your navigation stack, so you don’t see it on the screen.

> `controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Presenting UIAlertController over the new instance will not show user an alert since the `controller` here itself is not present on the screen.

You will need to present UIAlertController from the instance visible on screen(the initial one). You could change the function`show_alert` to the following:

```
class LoginModel{

 func showAlert(forController controller: UIViewController /*you could add title, message and other stuff here if needed.*/){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Some Message", 
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: 
   nil))

    controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And modify your call as follows:

```
LoginModel().showAlert(forController: self)
```